# Javascript to fetch json from unordered data

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I have below input code inside script code which comes like a string

[image]
The output should be below as a JSON object and extract flags and preference object. Need a solution using regex or any other way

flags = { "onFlag" : true, "offFlag : false }
Preference = { "onPreference" : true, "offPreference : false }

Comment: You can directly use `__LOADED_STATE__.context.flags` to get flags and `__LOADED_STATE__.context.Preference` to get Preference.

Comment: Entire script tag is coming as string  in a api

Comment: The __LOADED_STATE__ is not a proper JSON object. onFlag: false missing double quote. Is it the correct output or are you missing a double quote?

Comment: double quote is missed i it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to extract data inside the script tag and then parse content in javascript to generate JSON.

```
const regex = /<script[^>]+>(.*?)<\/script>/gs;
const str = `<script type="text/javascript">
window.__getRoute__=function() {
console.log('hi');
}

window.__LOADED_STATE__ = {
"context": {
    "flags": {"onFlag": true, "offFlag": false},
    "Preference": {"onPreference": true, "offPreference": false}
}
}
</script>`;
const m = regex.exec(str);
const json = new Function('var window={}; ' + m[1] + ' return window.__LOADED_STATE__')();

console.log(json.context.flags);
console.log(json.context.Preference);
```